# jenkins build process running forever

Tags: jenkins

*emphasized text*[image]

[image]

I want to stop jenkins process after build and start server.

but It's running forever like this...

[image]

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The application you are starting does not seem to have an end, because it seems you are running a `spring boot` application. After the successful build you start it rightaway inside the jenkins job. So it will never terminate, because the application is not terminating.

So I think you want to deploy the application somewhere and let it run maybe on the target VM?